# Loop in list of data row for excel

Tags: c#, excel

I have a console application that retrieves data from a web service. It will write the response on an excel file. My logic is fine with one data row, but if it is more than one, it's need writing on the excel file properly.

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int k = 0;

foreach (var response in responseList)
{
dt = response;
    for (i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j <= dt.Columns.Count - 1; j++)
        {
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

My problem with this code is that the excel rows that are being written are always the same.

Example: first response has 20 rows, second response has 10 rows. But after the loop, my excel only generated 20 rows. Seems like not all the data are not being written. Any ideas why?

**EDIT**

I tried the code below but still no luck.

```
int jOffset = 0;
int iOffset = 0;

foreach (var response in responseList)
{
    dt = response;
    for (i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j <= dt.Columns.Count - 1; j++)
        {
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + iOffset + 1, j + jOffset + 1] = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString();
        }
    }
    jOffset++;
    iOffset++;
}
```

Comment: Because you're starting from `0` each time. You are overwriting your previous responses each time. You need to store `iOffset` and `jOffset`, then write: `xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + iOffset + 1, j + jOffset + 1] = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString();`. Then of course, increment `iOffset` and `jOffset` as necessary

Comment: @Rob - see edit, i'm getting the same row count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this...

```
class YourClass
{
    //rowOffset as field
    int rowOffset = 0;

    void YourMethod()
    {
        //... your other codes here

        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int k = 0;

        dt = response;
        for (i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j <= dt.Columns.Count - 1; j++)
            {
                xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + iOffset + 1, j + 1] = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString();

            }
        }
        rowOffset += i; //the last 'i' (row) recorded will now be added to your row offset

        //...
    }
}
```

Basically, you only need a `rowOffset` and you should store it as a `field` to retain its value. Then, every after you finish one `loop` through the `response`, you add the last `i` (row #) to the `rowOffset` which will be the offset for succeeding loops.

EDIT: correction on rowOffset+=i

Comment: great! please re-read the explanation below the code since I editted it